# Got Solutions to a set of non liner equations in Matlab but not in Mathematica. Why?

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I was trying to solve a set of non linear equations using NSolve in mathematica. I got a result saying that no solution( {} ). My friend tried it in Matlab he was able to get a solution to the same set of equation for the same given parameters. Now my doubt is which one to trust?

I'm adding my functions bellow

```
    ClearAll[Evaluate[StringJoin[Context[], "*"]]]
    Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"]; 
    CleanSlate[]; 
    ClearInOut[];  

d[xt_, xv_, xo_, xb_] := (1189*(3*xv^2*(8/5 + xt/10) + (6*xv*xt*xo)/5 + 
      (6/5 - xt/10)*xo^2)*Cos[xb]^3)/3000000;  

ma1[xt_, xv_, xo_, xb_] := (1189*((48*xv^2)/5 + (3*xv^2*xt)/5 + 
      (16*xv*xt*xo)/5 + (18*xo^2)/5 - (3*xt*xo^2)/10)*Cos[xb]^2)/48000000;  

ma2[xt_, xv_, xo_, xb_] := (5/4)*xo^2*Cos[xb]*Sin[xb];  

q1[xt_, xv_, xo_, xb_] := (1189*(3*xt*((16*xv^2)/5 + (6*xo^2)/5) + 
      (1/10)*(-6*xv^2 - 16*xv*xt*xo + 3*xo^2))*Cos[xb]^3)/48000000;  

f11[xt_] := NSolve[{q1[xt, xv, xo, xb] == 0 && 
     d[xt, xv, xo, xb] - 133.05 == 0 && 
     ma1[xt, xv, xo, xb] - ma2[xt, xv, xo, xb] == 0}, {xv, xo, xb}, Reals, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 5]

f11[0.01]
```

kindly any one help me

In Matlab he got these values xv=232.9328, xo =290.8831, xb=1.7934 10^(-4); And the solutions accuracy was up to 5 digits in matlab

Comment: You can quit the kernel instead of going through your four-step cleaning process.

Comment: Plugging in the Matlab values does not get one close to zero for `d[xt, xv, xo, xb] - 133.05` or `ma1[xt, xv, xo, xb] - ma2[xt, xv, xo, xb]`.  Assuming that Matlab correctly did what it was asked, maybe the code in Matlab wasn't quite the same as the formulas here.  Showing the Matlab code could resolve that issue.

Answer (score 5):

Rationalized the numbers and use `Solve`

```
d[xt_,xv_,xo_,xb_]:=(1189*(3*xv^2*(8/5+xt/10)+(6*xv*xt*xo)/5+(6/5-xt/10)*xo^2)*Cos[xb]^3)/3000000;

ma1[xt_,xv_,xo_,xb_]:=(1189*((48*xv^2)/5+(3*xv^2*xt)/5+(16*xv*xt*xo)/5+(18*xo^2)/5-(3*xt*xo^2)/10)*Cos[xb]^2)/48000000;

ma2[xt_,xv_,xo_,xb_]:=(5/4)*xo^2*Cos[xb]*Sin[xb];

q1[xt_,xv_,xo_,xb_]:=(1189*(3*xt*((16*xv^2)/5+(6*xo^2)/5)+(1/10)*(-6*xv^2-16*xv*xt*xo+3*xo^2))*Cos[xb]^3)/48000000;

f11[xt_] := 
 Solve[{q1[xt, xv, xo, xb] == 0, d[xt, xv, xo, xb] - 13305/100 == 0, 
   ma1[xt, xv, xo, xb] - ma2[xt, xv, xo, xb] == 0}, {xv, xo, xb}]

f11[1/100] // N
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Use exact numbers and `Solve`: redefine

```
f11[xt_] := 
  Solve[{q1[xt, xv, xo, xb] == 0 && d[xt, xv, xo, xb] - 2661/20 == 0 &&
         ma1[xt, xv, xo, xb] - ma2[xt, xv, xo, xb] == 0}, {xv, xo, xb}]
```

and compute

```
f11[1/100]
```

gets you 8 solutions.